# Android Studio 2.3.3 & Support Library 26.0.0 :: Rendering AppCompatTextView in Previewer

Tags: android-studio

We've recently upgraded our company's Android Studio site build to 2.3.3 and we are suddenly encountering the following error in the xml previewer whenever we attempt to preview a layout.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor153.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We are using support library 26.0.0 in this particular example.

### Steps Taken

- Invalidate Caches & Restart
- Cleared .config and re-installed

This doesn't affect the rendering of the layout as the preview still generates, however it is annoying our developers as it appears to prevent specific errors from being shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For now a temporary fix might be to target API level 25 (if possible) until Google releases the stable release of API 26. Of course, this isn't optimal, but if you target API lvl 25 (appcompat-v7:25.3.1) the error disappears.